# Probability of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

This might be a really stupid question but...
Let $X$ be our continuous random variable.

Since $ P(X=c) = 0$ where C is any constant, does that mean that $P(a \le x \le b) = P(a < x \le b) = P(a \le x < b) = P(a < x < b)$

is the above true? if not why?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is true. For probability measures, we would like the following to hold: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint outcomes, then we require $P(A\text{ or } B)=P(A)+P(B)$. Because this holds, we can say that 
\begin{align*}
P(a\leq x\leq b)&=P(a\leq x<b \text{ or }x=b)\\
&=P(a\leq x<b)+P(x=b)\\
&=P(a\leq x<b)+0\\
&=P(a\leq x<b).
\end{align*}
Similarly you may deduce the other equalities.